# Swiftui: I can show the data from db in list ,but it shown nothing in picker, how can I fix it

Tags: swiftui, picker, swift5

Swiftui: I can show the data from db in list ,but it shown nothing in picker, how can I fix it
here is my ContentView:

```js
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()
   
    @State private var selectedStrength = 0
    var body: some View {
        
//              List(model.posts) { post in
//                Text(post.name)
//                  }
        

        Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("picker")) {
            ForEach(model.posts) { post in
               Text(post.name)


            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show us all relevant code. even better: show us reproducable copyable code. in your case: PostListViewModel is missing.

Answer (score 0):

try this or something similar:

```
ForEach(model.posts, id: \.self) { post in 
  Text(post.name)
}
```